# Classification of $4$th order PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When studying numerical methods, it seems that the different approaches are often presented as working better on certain equations over others (parabolic, elliptic, or hyperbolic).

I'm wondering, do these classifications translate to $4$th order PDEs?

Comment: Parabolic/Elliptic/Hyperbolic is called that way cause there's a similarity with conics' section. For $4$th order polynomial, I don't think there's a name for it.

Comment: Only partially. Note that with the main part of your equation (that is with the highest derivatives) you can identify an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix of its coefficients. If this matrix has exactly $n$ positive or negative eigenvalues, then the equation is elliptic, if there is one positive and $n-1$ negative (or vice versa) it is called hyperbolic, if there is zero eigenvalue and $n-1$ eigenvalues of the same sign, it is called parabolic.